# How to extract subject key identifier from x509 certificate through openssl

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I've created a x509 certificate using ec prime256v1 thorough openssl.
Can someone please let me know the way to extract subject key identifier from it using any openssl cli?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to read the field in the certificate or do you want the Subject Key Identifier corresponding to the used key?

Comment: I want to read from the certificate.

Comment: I'm able to capture it using grep -A1 "Subject Key Identifier" ca-cert.pem however i would like to know, if i can extract it through openssl command line

Comment: Quite sure you can't, not without using something like grep or awk.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how it works:

```sh
openssl x509 -in cer.der -inform DER -text | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g' | sed 's/ //g' | sed -n 's/.*SubjectKeyIdentifier:+\([A-F0-9:]*\)+.*/\1/p' | sed 's/\://g'
```

It is using `sed` to get the the Subject Detail Level.

Explaining the individual parts:

```sh
openssl x509 -in cer.der -inform DER -text
```

The next part is `sed` magic. It is removing all new lines and is replacing it with a `+`:

```sh
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g'
```

The next part is an easy `sed` magic. It is all blanks:

```sh
sed 's/ //g'
```

The next part is the interesting part and extracts the Subject key Identifier.

```sh
sed -n 's/.*SubjectKeyIdentifier:+\([A-F0-9:]*\)+.*/\1/p'
```

The last part is just removing the colons with `sed`. Maybe not needed in your case. maybe you also need it as binary.

```sh
sed 's/\://g'
```

If binary output is need add another pipe to the whole command:

```sh
openssl x509 -in CERT_S_SM_DPauth_ECDSA_BRP.der -inform DER -text | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/+/g' | sed 's/ //g' | sed -n 's/.*SubjectKeyIdentifier:+\([A-F0-9:]*\)+.*/\1/p' | sed 's/\://g' | xxd -r -p - subjkid.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

One can simply use `-subject` option with `openssl` and to specify `DER` or `PEM` format use `-inform` option, for example:

```
$ openssl x509 -inform DER -in myCert.der -noout -subject
subject= /C=IN/ST=Karnataka/L=Banaglore/O=FOO/OU=BAR

$ openssl x509 -inform PEM -in myCert.pem -noout -subject
subject= /C=IN/ST=Karnataka/L=Banaglore/O=FOO/OU=BAR
```

Note: By default we don't have to specify `-inform` option `PEM` format